# Can we replace Cocoapods with Swift Package Manager in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to add a new 3rd party library dependency like Alamofire in my project. Can we use it with the swift package manager?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add Alamofire in swift project by swift package manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43341734/how-to-add-alamofire-in-swift-project-by-swift-package-manager). There it asks for Alamofire but it should be true for all your pods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting with Xcode 11, you can use Swift Packages in your Xcode project. See [Apple's documentation on Swift Packages](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift_packages) for more information.

You can also learn more from the [Swift Package Manager repo](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager) on Github.

Comment: Is your answer made obsolete by Swift 5, released March 2019? https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/master/Documentation/PackageDescription.md#supportedplatform

Comment: @QED Per the project on Github, no. No change.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm confused about the newly available "platforms" option...

Comment: @QED I understand. My guess: They're adding support to define the platforms a package can run on ahead of actually being able to use Swift Package Manager for iOS, macOS, etc.

Comment: Now, it would appear that this is obsolete.

Comment: @keji I've updated my answer. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 2):

As per Apple Latest updates,

Thankful to this link for clarifying the doubt b/w cocoapods and package manager : 
My fav link for this topic is -  : https://zonneveld.dev/swift-package-manager-to-cocoapods/

**Swift Package Manager is available since 2016 but wasn’t that powerful yet. Recently, a new version of Swift Package Manager is released together with Xcode 11. This new version will finally allow you to replace CocoaPods.**

Apple Package Manager integrated with the Swift build system to automate the process of downloading, compiling, and linking dependencies.

**Remove CocoaPods from your project**

> pod deintegrate

**Migrate to Swift Package Manager**

> After removing CocoaPods, you can use the .xcodeproj file again. Open
>   your project, then go the menu bar and select File -> Swift Packages
>   -> Add Package Dependency.

As far as replacing cocoapds is concerned , i think YES.
Package Manager is more handy and more relevant as compared to cocoappods since in pods based project , if anything change then you need to explicitly do it but in case of package manager once you add dependency using this , XCode automatically adds the more stable and updated version to it .

Go for it , available for all the platforms iOS , tvOS , watchOS and MacOS too.